# How to flush stdout stream?

Tags: streams

I am aware that one can write to a terminal standard output like so:

```
WriteString["stdout","Some stuff","\r"];
```

Note here that I am using a carriage return on purpose, as part of some output monitoring. However, sometimes the output gets a bit messed up because it seems like stdout doesn't always update on the carriage return. I've seen this kind of thing before in C++ for example, and there I usually solve it by flushing the stdout stream. But I don't know how to do that, or anything analogous, in Mathematica. Help? :).

I am in a Linux environment, in case that matters.

Comment: Can you give steps to reproduce the problem?  (I cannot reproduce it. I tried `math -run 'WriteString["stdout", 123]; Pause[5]; Quit[]'`)

Comment: Well I am doing something more like this, although this example also seems to work fine: `math -run 'Table[Table[WriteString["stdout", "blah blah          "<>ToString[i]<>"   "<>ToString[j]<>"                      ","\r"],{i,1,10000}],{j,1,10000}]; Quit[]'`. I am not sure what causes the issue in my larger code. Maybe it is even related to my exact terminal environment or something. I guess my question stands independently of the exact problem though :).

Comment: I was asking because I don't think that you will get any answer unless you can show a reproducible example. Personally, I was under the impression that WriteString flushes right away. If this is not true, I would like to see it, so I can avoid problems in the future. I did search a bit about this topic a while ago (before your question), and I found nothing.  Also, what actually happens depends on how you run Mathematica.  If you use the new-in-11 `wolframscript`, the behaviour may be entirely different. I am not sure about the older script mode.